# How to create a "relationship" of class properties in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Question(models.Model):
   whom = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='whom_Question')
   who_liked = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='who_liked_QUESTION')

class Notification(models.Model)
   who_liked = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='who_liked_Notification')
   whom = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='whom_Notification')
```

Is it possible to create a sort of relationship between properties of those classes, or is it inevitable to save the same information in different classes? As far as I am into documentation the only way is to create one more class and then use OneToOne relationships, right?

Comment: Do you mean to create a ForgeinKey between the classes? define "relationship" better please.

Comment: @idik I mean to relate properties like we can relate classes, so that there would no need to save information in two classes